# Using Dask in Python to run function in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask

I'm trying to use Dask.delayed to have a function be computed in parallel.
The function BL.BLSN has 1 argument which is a string.

```
runs=['forcing.dat','forcing.dat','forcing.dat','forcing.dat','forcing.dat','forcing.dat']
dfs = [delayed(BL.BLSN)(fn) for fn in runs]
```

When I print dfs I get a list of the delayed objects. Which is what I was expecting.

> [Delayed('BLSN-630cb6bf-7104-4d41-b5fb-544116fec7ed'), 
>   Delayed('BLSN-150a5d45-073a-48af-af03-6e85f809617c'), 
>   Delayed('BLSN-484e7d71-af09-4a1f-be28-42358ef745e9'), 
>   Delayed('BLSN-2f2f2cc1-76bc-4c29-839d-091255556f35'), 
>   Delayed('BLSN-8aae0a06-d607-4a98-89a7-cfd2c877bf11'), 
>   Delayed('BLSN-f0131a69-2bfd-4153-94c1-2d3ef4973772')

]

However, when I try:

`dfs.compute()`

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'compute'
```

What is the best way to have compute operate on each object in the list?

Comment: You have a list of Delayed objects since you are using the list comprehension. Call `compute` on each of them or see @mdurant 's answer

Comment: If you call compute() sequentially, you will wait for each result and not experience any parallelism

Answer (score 2):

You want the function form of [`compute`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.compute) rather than the method:

```
import dask
dask.compute(*dfs)
```

This will run in parallel (with the usual caveats), and if tasks share dependencies, they will be shared intelligently.